# Show that $\int_{t=-1}^1\frac{d^i}{dt^i}(1-t^2)^i\frac{d^j}{dt^j}(1-t^2)^jdt=0$ $\forall$ i,j distinct

Tags: linear-algebra, definite-integrals

This is a question from example sheet for linear algebra course.
 Let $P_n$ be the (n+1-dimensional) space of real polynomials of degree ≤ n. Define 
$$(f,g)=\int_{t=-1}^1f(t)g(t)dt$$
Let $s_k\in P_n$ be defined by $s_k(t)=\frac{d^k}{dt^k}(1-t^2)^k$

My question is how to prove that $\forall i\neq j, (s_i,s_j)=0$.

Comment: Integration by parts?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have tried integration by parts but how do I evaluate $[\frac{d^{i-1}}{dt^{i-1}}(1-t^2)^i\frac{d^j}{dt^j}(1-t^2)^j]_{-1}^1$?

Comment: Surely it's zero?

Comment: I might be wrong. But could it be that $s_k$ is an even function if $k$ is even? And an odd function if $k$ is odd? If that is the case: If i and j are not equal one of them is even and one is odd. Product of odd and even function is odd. Hence integral is Zero.

Comment: But $i \neq j$ does not imply one is even and one is odd. For example $i=2$ and $j=4$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that... Maybe it can still help?

Comment: If one is even and one is odd, the integrand is odd and the integral zero. In all other cases (odd, odd and even, even) the integrand is even and maybe that can be exploited...

Comment: @thomasfermi I just posted the answer so have a look at it if you're interested!

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i \neq j$, then without loss of generality, can assume $i>j$. Then using integration by parts, get 
$$(s_i,s_j)=[\frac{d^{i-1}}{dt^{i-1}}((1-t^2)^i)\frac{d^j}{dt^j}((1-t^2)^j)]_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{i-1}}{dt^{i-1}}((1-t^2)^i)\frac{d^{j+1}}{dt^{j+1}}((1-t^2)^j)dt$$

But note that $\frac{d^{i-1}}{dt^{i-1}}((1-t^2)^i)$ evaluated at $t=\pm1$ is both 0 since the multiplicity of $(1-t)$ and $(1+t)$ in $(1-t^2)^i$ are both greater than $i-1$. Then repeating the process $i$ times, get

$$(s_i,s_j)=-\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{i-1}}{dt^{i-1}}((1-t^2)^i)\frac{d^{j+1}}{dt^{j+1}}((1-t^2)^j)dt$$

$$=(-1)^i\int_{-1}^1(1-t^2)^i\frac{d^{i+j}}{dt^{i+j}}((1-t^2)^j)dt$$

But since $i+j>2j$ and $(1-t^2)^j$ is a polynomial of degree $2j$, $\frac{d^{i+j}}{dt^{i+j}}((1-t^2)^j)=0.$
Hence, $(s_i,s_j)=0$.